# Coding Logic for a Daily Scheduler

Tags: php, logic

I want to create a daily scheduler for my employees to visually see their workday. A table would be fine, with employees being on x axis, and hours on the left. 00:00 - 24:00

I have a table with employees (6 rows), and a list of jobs to do. The jobs have a start time, and end time (includes breaks).

I want to create a scheduler which automatically assigns jobs to employees, minimizing the number of employees.

sample:

```
id  | Start_time    | end_time
-----------------------------------
1   | 08:00     | 10:00
2   | 10:00     | 12:00
3   | 12:00     | 13:00
4   | 12:30     | 13:30
5   | 12:45     | 14:00
6   | 13:00     | 14:00

job 1,2,3 get assigned to employee 1.
job 4, gets assigned to employee 2.
job 5 gets assigned to emloyee 3.
job 6 gets assigned to employee 1.
```

I have been going at this for 2 days now without success. I tried fullcalendar and weekcalendar, without success.

Comment: You need 3 tables at least. One to hold employees, one for jobs, the other to match the employee & job id's.

Comment: that's not a problem. I have an employees table and jobs table. adding a 3rd is not a problem but I need a logic to how the jobs are assigned with the given pattern/requirements.

Comment: I would have a page to add a job and/or employee. A page to assign jobs. To assign a job I would have a drop down for the employees and available jobs. I guess you could do all this via ajax on one page. Then on submit this creates a new record ijn the assigned table. The jobs table would have an is_assigned (yes/no or 1/0) column

Comment: I want the jobs to be assigned automatically. This is the logic I can't figure out.